# Azure Linux web app - Error eisdir illegal operation on a directory read

Tags: reactjs, azure, kubernetes, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I am getting an issue with my web app hosted on linux app service plan. It is a static gatsby site and is running perfectly fine in kubernetes. I want to run this in Azure web app (Linux app service plan) but the refresh is not working except for the home page. This works perfectly in my local as well. I have below settings in my web app: -

[image]

Suppose my website homepage URL is abcd.com and when I navigate to the help page (abcd.com/help) it works fine. But, if I refresh the page or try to go to the URL directly it gives me an error: - "Sorry, check with the site admin for error: EISDIR ..". I checked in kudu control and can see the same error. I compared the zip deployment files for the web app with the Kubernetes version and both look the same.I am not sure what is the issue here. Could someone help?

Comment: Try `pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon` or `pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon --spa` .

Comment: I tried both as shown in the image. It didn't work.

Comment: If possible, can you create a new test sample for us ? If we can reproduce the problem, then we can locate the error and deal with it.

Comment: yes sure, I will create and share the repo link in some time.

Comment: Remember not to put confidential or business information, just create a new demo.

Comment: you can use this one also -https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default. I checked for this one and this is having the same issue when you try to refresh after navigating to page-2.

Comment: @JasonPan Did you get a chance to look into this?

Comment: I tried to use your project and reproduced your problem. I need time to try to solve it.

Comment: I am facing exact same issue, did you find any solution to this ?

Comment: @ArunRana Could you tell me more about your app? Are you also using gatsby?

Comment: @TechGuru I am using next js, Here are the details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67136093/next-js-app-on-azure-linux-web-app-error-eisdir-illegal-operation-on-a-directo

Comment: @ArunRana Check for my answer there, if it helps.

Comment: @TechGuru still same issue

Comment: It would appear this still hasn't been fixed.