# Next js app on Azure Linux web app - Error eisdir illegal operation on a directory read

Tags: reactjs, linux, next.js, azure-webapps

I am getting an issue with my web app hosted on linux app service plan which is a static next js site and is running perfectly fine in Azure storage with cdn & window based web app (with extra files like web.config & server.js)

I would like to run this in Azure web app (Linux app service plan) but the refresh is not working except for the home page. This works perfectly in my local as well. I have below settings in my web app

[image]

Suppose my website homepage URL is xyz.azurewebsites.net and when I navigate to the help page (xyz.azurewebsites.net/professionals) it works fine. But, if I refresh the page or try to go to the URL directly it gives me the below error

[image]

here is run logs in local

[image]

I am deploying it through the bitbucket pipeline as below

```
image: node:10.15.3

pipelines:
   default: 
      - step:
        name: Install dependencies
        caches:
          - node
        script:             
          - npm install
    - step:
        name: build
        caches:
          - node
        script:
           - npm run build                             
           - apt update && apt install zip            
           - zip -r out-$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER.zip . 
        artifacts:
          - out-*.zip                                

    - step:
        name: "Deploy to Azure Web App - Dev"
        deployment: Staging
        script:
          - echo "only for specific brnach"
          - pipe: microsoft/azure-web-apps-deploy:1.0.0
            variables:
                AZURE_APP_ID: $AZURE_APP_ID
                AZURE_PASSWORD: $AZURE_PASSWORD
                AZURE_TENANT_ID: $AZURE_TENANT_ID
                AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP: $AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP
                AZURE_APP_NAME: $APP_NAME
                ZIP_FILE: "out-$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER.zip"
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try adding this in settings => Configuration?

[image]

Comment: I have added though same issue

Comment: Are you using a different port? Could you show run logs when you are running locally?

Comment: Are you using 3000 in WEBSITE_PORT configuration setting?

Comment: correct setting name was WEBSITES_PORT. I did set value 3000 and removed the startup command now it has 2 problems redirecting & refresh so startup command is mandatory which tell application to redirect route to index.html

Comment: How are you publishing your application on Azure web app? In my case, I created a docker image and pushed it to the azure container registry.

Comment: I am publishing using bitbucket pipeline (updated in question )

Comment: I had tried the same way earlier with the Linux App Service plan and was getting the same issue. But when I deployed in Windows app service plan, it worked perfectly. Due to cost, I had to use the Linux app service plan. So, I decided to use docker. If you don't have that constraint then you could try the windows app service. I hope this will help you.